# how to configure && make && make install inside a CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, configure

I am migrating the compilation toolchain of a project from a simple "./configure; make" to "CMake".

One step of the compilation phase is to configure and make some 3rd parties such as patched lapack library if I choose to use this library instead of the system one.

My problem is that I don't know how to untar an archive, configure and compile the associated sources that will be linked to my project.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Seb

Comment: You should look into the CMake module [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html).

Comment: Hi Angew, indeed it was the right module to make what I want. Thank you. Unfortunately, when I link the generated static libraries to my executable with the target_link_libraries option, I got a lot of undefined references. I check the symbols into my libraries with the nm command and they seems to be well defined. Did I do something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I've never actually used the `ExternalProject` module (that's why I only added a comment, not an answer). You might want to edit your question with more information (show how you use `ExternalProject` and what the results are), perhaps someone will know.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Angew. A few days ago, I got the same issue without using ExternalProjet.. My project contains a lot of modules that I compiled into static libraries and that I linked with my final executable. I got several undefined references even if the symbols are well defined in the libraries. I bypass this problem using object libraries... Maybe you have an idea on what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Sounds like a separate question. You could ask one (after searching for a solution), but don't forget to put all relevant info (ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in there.